# Render only fields in a Django inline_formset

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

I want to render only fields in a Django inline_formset.

This is my template:

```
<div id="storage">
    <h1>Storage</h1>
    {% for form in storage_formset %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ form.help_texts }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                {{ form.errors }}
                {{ form }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And this is my form:

```
help = {'field1' : "help1", 'field2' : "help2"}

StorageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(WorkOrder, Storage, min_num=0,
max_num=2, validate_min=True, validate_max=True, extra=1, help_texts=help, 
fields=('field1', 'field2'))
```

This one works, but when it renders, it renders everything (field and field name) in the form and I want it to only render the field. Other thing is that the `help_texts` don't work (I don't know if I'm using it right).

If I use:

```
{{ form.field1 }}
```

It renders field1, but I want to do it dynamically, so I don't have to repeat again and again.

And if I use:

```
{{ form.fields }}
```

It renders a bunch of code

```
OrderedDict(
[('field1', <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0x7f8f6409c890>), 
('field2', <django.forms.fields.IntegerField object at 0x7f8f6409c650>), 
(u'id', <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x7f8f6409c1d0>), 
(u'DELETE', <django.forms.fields.BooleanField object at 0x7f8f6409cc90>), 
('parent_field', <django.forms.models.InlineForeignKeyField object at 0x7f8f659c4e10>)])
```

I don't know what else to do.

Thank you if you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code to only render fields and their associated help texts:

```
<div id="storage">
    <h1>Storage</h1>
    {% for form in storage_formset %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ form.help_texts }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                {{ form.errors }}
                {% for field in form %}
                    {{ field }} {{ field.help_text }}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

For more information about accessing form fields in a template visit the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields).